# Nested Map loops return not returning anything

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native

I have a nested map loop (the outer for rendering each day, and the inner for rendering the elements within the day. The issue I'm having, is that nothing is being returned in the return block. The area where there should be something rendering, there is nothing there. First of all, I'm not sure why nothing is being returned, when I only had one loop (the elements within the day one). Second, is there any way to maybe combine the loops?

```
{
  daysArray.map(days => {
    var dayState = eval('global.that.state.' + days);
    var dayStateArray = Object.values(dayState);
    dayStateArray.map(i => {
      return ( 
        <Card 
          style={{ justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}
          key = {i.id}
        >
          <Text key={i.name}>{i.name.replace('&amp;', '&')}</Text>
          <Text key={i.start_timestamp}>Starting: {i.start_timestamp</Text> 
          <Text key={i.end_timestamp}>Ending: {i.end_timestamp}</Text
        </Card>
      )
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: you forget to return dayStateArray.map(...)

Comment: you have not `return` statement on your first `map` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason nothing is being rendered is because nothing is being returned from first map. You would need to return nested map for elements to be rendered.

```
{
  daysArray.map(days => {
    var dayState = eval('global.that.state.' + days);
    var dayStateArray = Object.values(dayState);
    return dayStateArray.map(i => {
      return ( 
        <Card 
          style={{ justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}
          key={i.id}
        >
          <Text key={i.name}>{i.name.replace('&amp;', '&')}</Text> 
          <Text key={i.start_timestamp}>Starting: {i.start_timestamp}</Text> 
          <Text key={i.end_timestamp}>Ending: {i.end_timestamp}</Text> 
        </Card>
      )
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: This works, but how would I get something to return in the outer loop (a text element showing the current day for the results)

Comment: You can return a `<div>` from outerloop enclosing date and result from inner map.

Comment: I don't think you can return twice in the outer map loop? I tried that and it stops execution of the inner map.

Comment: You can have return only once. What I meant was in single return have a `<div>` wrapping date and result from inner map. Something like: `return <div><p>{date}</p>dayStateArray.map(i => ...)</div>`

Answer (score 2):

I think the inner map function returns value to the outer map function.So use return from inner map function to return to the outer map function.

I have a sample code snippet:

```
var a=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]

var b=a.map((x)=>{
  let c= x.map((y)=>{
      console.log(y)
       return y*2
   })
   return c
})

console.log(b)
```