# Nested map not returning

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

This code should return [1, 7]. It returns undefined. I can't figure out how to get the function to return.

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50342853/nested-map-loops-return-not-returning-anything) but it has not helped.

```
let sumPairs = (arr, s) => {
  arr.map((item1, index) => {
    return arr.map((item2) => {
      if (item1 + item2 === s) 
        console.log([item1, item2])
        //[ 1, 7 ]
        //[ 4, 4 ]
        //[ 7, 1 ]
        return [item1, item2]
    }, index);
  });
}
```

Comment: Your initial `arr.map` is never returned from `sumPairs` function. Change to: `let sumPairs = (arr, s) => arr.map((item1, index) => { /* ... */ })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you simply forgot a single return in the `sumPairs` function :)

```
let sumPairs = (arr, s) => {
  return arr.map((item1, index) => { // < here
    return arr.map((item2) => {
      if (item1 + item2 === s) 
        return [item1, item2]
    }, index);
  });
}
```